# In Tastypie is there a way to change a resources excludes based on the authentication?

Tags: tastypie

Consider the example of a user resource that has profile pic and email fields. Where any user may see any other users profile pic but a user may only see their own email address.

Is it possible to setup tastypie so that the set of excluded fields can be varied based on the authenticated user?

I realize that an alternative approach is to create separate full and restricted user resources. But for the moment I just want to know whether the approach of limiting the fields based on user authentication is even doable in tastypie.

Also it doesn't have to be the excludes, in the same vein is there a way instead to change the  fields property based on the requesting user?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think excluded fields can be brought back into the picture in an elegant fashion. You could probably manipulate the object list based on the request using some object manipulation by including the `get_object_list` in your resource

But it would be much better and more logical for you to use the `apply_limits` method in your custom authorization class.

Comment: I added an additional bit to the question about excludes vs fields

Comment: from my understanding apply_limits would be the primary mechanism used if I split it into two resources, the restricted user resource would use apply_limits to control who can see which users. Is that what you were getting at? or is there more that I am missing?

Comment: Like apply_limits get_object_list seems to apply at the entity level, excluding or including whole users, not fields with the users, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do it. 
If you define email to be a separate field, not the one of the User(might work and with that but never did it). 
You can define dehydrate_email where the bundle.request contains the current request and you could get it. It won't be exactly excluded as a field but it will be None for others.

Answer (score 0):

I created a ModelResource subclass that can be multiple inherited into the required ModelResource instances. Like:

```
class ResourceThatNeedsToExcludeSomeFields(ExcludeResource, ModelResource):
    pass
```

It takes in the fields to be excluded via GET parameters (like "&exclude=username")

```
class ExcludeResource(ModelResource):
"""
Generic class to implement exclusion of fields in all the ModelResource classes
All ModelResource classes will be muliple inherited by this class, whose dehydrate method has been overriden
"""
# STACK: How to exclude some fields from a resource list created by tastypie?
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    # I was taking the exclude fields from get paramaters as a comma separated value
    if bundle.request.GET.get('exclude'):
        exclude_fields = bundle.request.GET.get('exclude').split(',')
        for field in exclude_fields:
            if str(field) in bundle.data.keys():
                del bundle.data[str(field)]
    return bundle
```

You can modify this to get the exclude fields based on user group (or whatever criteria you base the fields on) like this:

```
class ExcludeResource(ModelResource):
"""
Generic class to implement exclusion of fields in all the ModelResource classes
All ModelResource classes will be muliple inherited by this class, whose dehydrate method has been overriden
"""
# STACK: How to exclude some fields from a resource list created by tastypie?
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    exclude_fields = <get a comma separated list of fields to be excluded based in bundle.request.user>
    for field in exclude_fields:
        if str(field) in bundle.data.keys():
            del bundle.data[str(field)]
    return bundle
```

However, this snippet will not work for related resources specified with "full=True"